# How to get specific item from 'bs4.element.Tag'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
>>> for i in fluc_final:print(i)
...
<td class="fluc flucFinal flucMin" data-bettype="Flucs" data-compid="38188640" data-eid="6091412" data-hash="-405085059" data-mtype="R" data-price="8">8</td>
<td class="fluc flucFinal flucMax" data-bettype="Flucs" data-compid="38188641" data-eid="6091412" data-hash="-405118818" data-mtype="R" data-price="16">16</td>
```

How do I get the data-price value as a float?

Comment: see this [example here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

html = '''8

```
<td class="fluc flucFinal flucMax" data-bettype="Flucs" data-compid="38188641" data-eid="6091412" data-hash="-405118818" data-mtype="R" data-price="16">16</td>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

prices = soup.find_all('td')
for data in prices:
    price = float(data.text)
    print ('%.02f' %price)
```